# Iterate through a python list of list and delete lists depending on a condition

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of list in python as follows:

```
[['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.59', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.37', '150612899', 'google.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.33', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.47', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]
```

Column 1: epoch_time
 Column 2: serial_number
 Column 3: domain
 Column 4: server

How would I iterate through the list of list for each domain, so that if the serial_number is equal to the serial_number for 8.8.8.8, the list is deleted so the final output is as follows:

```
['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'],
['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'],
['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]
```

Comment: does it have to be on list of lists? cause I think it is much easier to convert it to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: no..not a compulsion..pandas data frame works as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
a = [['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.59', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.37', '150612899', 'google.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.33', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.47', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]

remove = [item[1] for item in a if item[3]=='8.8.8.8']
clean = [item for item in a if item[1] not in remove or item[3]=='8.8.8.8']
print clean
```

Comment: I would use a `frozenset` for `remove`. In other words `remove = frozenset(item[1] for item in a if item[3] == '8.8.8.8')`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write any code, so I won't either.

- Create a set of banned `serial_numbers`
- Iterate on the list once.
- Add the serial number to `serial_numbers` if `ip` is `8.8.8.8`.
- Iterate on the list a second time, with a list comprehension.
- Keep the elements if `ip` is `8.8.8.8` or if `serial_number` isn't in
  `serial_numbers`.

It will be short to write and fast to run.

Answer (score 1):

I would sort the list to make rows with addresses `8.8.8.8` appear at the start, then I would iterate through the list, marking the key (serial,domain) when inserted to be sure to insert only once.

```
l = [['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.59', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.37', '150612899', 'google.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.33', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.47', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]

inserted = set()
result = []
for row in sorted(l,key=lambda r: r[3]!="8.8.8.8"):
    timestamp,serial,domain,server = row
    k = (serial,domain)
    if k in inserted:
        pass  # already in result: skip
    else:
        result.append(row)
        inserted.add(k)
```

results in:

```
[['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'], ['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'], ['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8'], ['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'], ['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'], ['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the serial_number associated with your server (8.8.8.8) and then ignore them while forming your list with an if condition!

```
data=[['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'],
      ['1490026791.59', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '208.67.222.222'],
      ['1490026791.57', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.4.4'],
      ['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
      ['1490026791.37', '150612899', 'google.com', '208.67.220.220'],
      ['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
      ['1490026791.33', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.4.4'],
      ['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
      ['1490026791.57', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.220.220'],
      ['1490026791.47', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.222.222'],
      ['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'],
      ['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]


serv='8.8.8.8'
fil=filter(None,map(lambda x: x[1] if x[3]==serv else None, data))
print [i for i in data if i[1] not in fil or i[3] == serv]
```

Output:

```
[['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'], ['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'], ['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'], ['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'], ['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'], ['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]
```

If you time the solution,
On using list comprehension (few other solutions),

```
7.9870223999e-05
```

On using lambda and map

```
4.81605529785e-05
```

This should be a problem in this case, but when the data set is large, time does matter.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just create your filter list, then apply the filtering on a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.59', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.37', '150612899', 'google.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.33', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8'],
 ['1490026791.57', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.220.220'],
 ['1490026791.47', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '208.67.222.222'],
 ['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4'],
 ['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']]
>>>
>>> ip_check = '8.8.8.8'
>>> filter_serials = [lst[1] for lst in l if lst[3] == ip_check]
>>> filter_serials
['2010113820', '150612899', '2017032001']
>>> 
>>> output_list = [lst for lst in l if lst[3] == ip_check or lst[1] not in filter_serials]
>>> 
>>> for lst in output_list:
    print(lst)


['1490011456.91', '2010113819', 'amazon.com', '208.67.220.220']
['1490026791.55', '2010113820', 'amazon.com', '8.8.8.8']
['1490026791.35', '150612898', 'google.com', '208.67.222.222']
['1490019411.19', '150612899', 'google.com', '8.8.8.8']
['1490026791.45', '2017032000', 'intuit.com', '8.8.4.4']
['1490026791.43', '2017032001', 'intuit.com', '8.8.8.8']
```